# How to install rxLib component in Delphi xe5?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, jvcl

I found a couple of downloads for rxLib component of Delphi xe5 but not a clear instruction on how to install it.

Comment: RxLib support ended with Delphi v.6 in 2000. The official continuation, together with some other dead opensource libs, is JediVCL. However JVCL also came through some restructuring attempts. So best course would be to install JedivCL and find there similar components to those RxLib ancestors.

Comment: Official instructions are at http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Installing_Component_Packages

Answer (score 4):

For future questions, please be more especific with the error or problem that you have.

1. Download [this unnoficial version of RxLib from here](http://www.micrel.cz/RxLib/dfiles.htm) that work
   with Delphi 2005, 2006, 2007, 2009, 2010, XE, XE2, XE3, XE4, XE5,
   XE6, XE7, XE8, 10-Seattle and 10.1-Berlin.
2. Open the ProjectGroup especific for your version.
3. Compile and install the packages

Be sure that you copy the files inside a location with read/write permissions.

If you have an error, please modify your original message and update this information.

Comment: Thank you, but the link does not work. I have been there since morning

Comment: @lfenyi  This link work fine for me too. From Spain. Try to use a proxy (https://kproxy.com/) and paste the link of file.

Comment: You've come to the wrong place. This site isn't for asking questions about your problems downloading files. You should perhaps find a forum.

Comment: @Ifeanyi: No, we're not going to email you the files. Please take the [tour] and review the  [help] pages before posting here again. You need a serious lesson in what this site is and how it works. We're not your code finding service, we don't correspond with anyone except through this site so it will benefit others in the future, and we are absolutely not anyone's personal delivery service.

Comment: Just for the record: the link doesn't work for me either: Error "www.micrel.cz’s server DNS address could not be found." But using the internet archive works: http://web.archive.org/web/20160423095103/http://www.micrel.cz/RxLib/dfiles.htm